# vertical list view with horizontal scroll view android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a list view with horizontal scroll view. I am getting a logcat error "null pointer exception " while setting list view adapter. My list view should be displayed inside sherlock fragment

```
public class Trending extends SherlockFragment

{
List<String> list;
    ListView prog_list;


// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
          View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trendslay, container,false);       
          prog_list = (ListView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
          return prog_list;
         }


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);
    prog_list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same requirement of creating a Horizontal ListView inside Vertical ListView and I had tried to manage that using [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) for Horizontal scrolling of ListView items with Vertical scrolling. You can check my demo for the same on github as [`VerticalHorizontalListView.`](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView)

Comment: Nice tutorial but here you're just scrolling each row of `ListView` horizontally not complete `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vertical scroll view

and in your layout give `android:fillViewport="true"` this will give you horizontal scroll effect without using horizontal scroll view

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `prog_list.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);` after `setAdapter();`

Comment: but it still shows null pointer exception on set adapter ...... i have implemented the list viewin sherlockfragment class......

Comment: that only specifies if the horizontal scroll bar should be drawn. It doesn't affect behavior in any way

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trendslay,container,false);       
      prog_list = (ListView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lv1);


    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");
    list.add("hi");
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("how r u");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>getActivity(),
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);
    prog_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return  myFragmentView ;
     }
```

Comment: It is useful for other users if you edit your question and explain what makes the difference.

Comment: It needs to return the fragment view instead of listview in oncreateview that's the reason it returns null pointer exception.